# Wooden window frame in shower

Tags: water, wood

The genius design of my 60 year old home includes a wooden Window frame in my shower.

I believe the prior owner took baths only to avoid problems with this. For me it's constantly growing mold and the wood is not looking good.

What's the easiest effective way to handle this? There's not enough room in the show for there to be a window curtain. Can I seal or cover the wood with something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **What's the easiest effective way to handle this?**

You could

- Clean it, scrape/sand it and slather it with yacht varnish annually.
- Replace it with PVC or Aluminium.
- Brick it up (maybe with glass bricks?)

The easiest and most effective way to do anything is to throw vast amounts of cash at tradesmen until everything's OK or you are declared bankrupt.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this though hiring someone wouldn't be very easy for me because I have no money. That's why I come to the DIY SE :)

Comment: Could one remove the finish and paint on penetrating mildewcide, or is the fungal infestation all the way inside so replacement of the moldy wooden elements the only effective solution?

Comment: @Jim. That might help but my experience with shower sealants that claim "stops mould growth and fungi." is that they don't do that forever. You have to also remove surface water and moisture in the air for a long term solution. Another consideration (apart from mold) is that applying hot steam and water daily to a piece of wood, and leaving it wet, takes its toll on any finish and (eventually) on the structure of the wood. What I find with treated softwood outdoors is that eventually the surface looks fine and seems hard but cracks have opened up the untreated interior and it has rotted away.

Comment: Using an anti fowling paint will prevent growth that is 1 way they keep things from growing on the bottom of boats, the same additives can be added to paint, not sure if it is ok for interior work but here in Oregon some homes have to have it on the outside to keep the mold from growing.

Answer (score 0):

If the wall the window is set in is tiled just remove one square of tile around window wall edge and inset a flat pane of tempered glass.  I personally did this on a home with 4x4 tiles and set a rain glass pane in and grouted it. Never have had a call back so guess it works.